# Conway's Game of Life - Unity 3D Implementation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to implement Conway's Game of Life using Unity 3D and C#... But somehow I'm unable to make my algorithm complete any of these patterns:

[image: Conway's Patterns]

When I try to follow some patterns, this is what happens:

[image: My Result]

This is the code responsable:

```cs
    public int GetAliveNeighbors(GameObject cell) {
        int aliveNeighbors = 0;

        for (int i = -1; i <= 1; i++) {
            for (int j = -1; j <= 1; j++) {
                
                if (i == 0 && j == 0)
                    continue; // Ignores current cell

                //Debug.Log($"i: {i}, j: {j}");

                int x = Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.x) + i;
                int y = Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.y) + j;

                if (x < 0 || x >= gridSize.x || y < 0 || y >= gridSize.y)
                    continue; //Check if inside of the grid

                if (cells[x, y].GetComponent<CellBehaviour>().isAlive)
                    aliveNeighbors++;
            }
        }

        return aliveNeighbors;
    }

    public void UpdateGrid() {

        cellsToUpdate = new GameObject[(int)gridSize.x, (int)gridSize.y];

        foreach (GameObject cell in cells) {
            // Less than 2 neighbors, die by underpopulation
            // More than 3 neighbors, die by overpopulation
            // Exactly 3 neighbors, become alive
            // Exactly 2 or 3 neighbors, stay alive

            int aliveNeighbors = GetAliveNeighbors(cell);

            if (cell.GetComponent<CellBehaviour>().isAlive) {

                if (aliveNeighbors < 2 || aliveNeighbors > 3) {
                    cellsToUpdate[Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.y)] = cell;
                    cellsToUpdate[Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.y)].GetComponent<CellBehaviour>().SetAlive(false);
                }

            } else {
                if (aliveNeighbors == 3) {
                    cellsToUpdate[Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.y)] = cell;
                    cellsToUpdate[Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.y)].GetComponent<CellBehaviour>().SetAlive(true);
                }
            }
        }

        foreach (GameObject cell in cellsToUpdate) {
            if (cell != null)
                cells[Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.x), Mathf.RoundToInt(cell.transform.position.y)].GetComponent<CellBehaviour>().SetAlive(cell.GetComponent<CellBehaviour>().isAlive);
        }
    }
```

Any idea/suggestions to implement in these? I've been in the past few hours trying to find the error.

I'm comparing my results to [this site](https://playgameoflife.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you need two copies of the grid, one for the current state and another for the next state. In the above as you iterate through the cells you're setting some alive/dead which then impact the outcome within the loop. Good luck with the project, cellular automata are fun.

Comment: So, I tried what you told me... But after some testing, it seems that is only finding half of the alive neighbors. (I've placed one cell, and it told me that only 4 has a living neighbor instead of 8). Any suggestions on that? I've updated the code in the post

Comment: I’ve fixed it by changing the CellsToUpdate into a custom Object list and updating the main board according to each object in the list